# Group Policy : Outlook Spell check

Tags: windows, group-policy, outlook

I need a group policy that can be rolled out to enable "Check spelling before sending" to the entire domain.

I have checked the Goog's and everyone seems to say its not possible, however it is always attached to questions like "I want users to be able to switch it on and off and then not have it override"

We do not require this, just a plain force enable.

If its not possible via GPO, suggestions via CommandLine/Powershell/KaseayRMM scripting would be much appreciated.

Comment: as 
Office  Administrative Templates
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179081.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

or you may create a script which change registry value and deploy it to domain 
https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27413271/enable-always-check-spelling-before-sending.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been possible since at least Office 2010. You'll need to add the appropriate Office Group Policy templates and configure the setting.